# I get error with amfphp

Tags: php, amfphp

How can i solve this problem?
The error is: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /.../amfphp/core/amf/app/Gateway.php on line 134

```
public static function service() {

        //Set the parameters for the charset handler
        CharsetHandler::setMethod($this->_charsetMethod); // the problem points here
        CharsetHandler::setPhpCharset($this->_charsetPhp);
        CharsetHandler::setSqlCharset($this->_charsetSql);

        //Attempt to call charset handler to catch any uninstalled extensions
        $ch = new CharsetHandler('flashtophp');
        $ch->transliterate('?');

        $ch2 = new CharsetHandler('sqltophp');
        $ch2->transliterate('?');

        $GLOBALS['amfphp']['actions'] = $this->actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$this` variable inside `static` methods, cause class instance does not exist. Static methods know nothing about instance of the class, you can treat these methods as `class methods`, not `instance methods`. Looks like you need to remove `static` modifier of this function. Check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for further explanation.

Comment: I had an error before this one, so i check it on google and the fix was to put `public static` before the function. When i done it the error dissapeared but this one came...

Comment: @tyrlaka, you should check what really`static` methods are, and how to use them. Static methods/properties are not silverbullet, they are just part of OOP with their own restrictions and profits. Check the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php. If you need any other help – update your question or publish a new one :)